# c# Use NLog with Mongo

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, logging, nlog

i would log my data with NLog and MongoDB. I configured my NLog.config like this:

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="NLog.Mongo"/>
</extensions>
...
 <target xsi:type="Mongo"
        name="mongo"
        includeDefaults="false"
        connectionString="mongodb://localhost"
        collectionName="myCollection"
        databaseName="logs"
        cappedCollectionSize="26214400">
  <field name="_id" layout="${Id}"/>
  <field name="ts" layout="${Timestamp}" bsonType="DateTime"/>
  <field name="cap" layout="${ApplicationCaller}" />
</target>
```

But how can i pass value ID, Timestamp, ApplicationCaller in my log??
I try this code:

```
public void LogExceptionOnMongo(string callIdentifier, string applicationCaller)
{
     var _myLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("mongo");
     var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Fatal, "", "Exception");
     logEventInfo.Properties["CallIdentifier"] = callIdentifier;
     logEventInfo.Properties["TimeStamp"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
     logEventInfo.Properties["ApplicationCaller"] = applicationCaller;

     _myLogger.Log(logEventInfo);
}
```

and this configuration:

```
<target xsi:type="Mongo"
        name="mongo"
        includeDefaults="false"
        connectionString="mongodb://localhost"
        collectionName="myCollection"
        databaseName="logs"
        cappedCollectionSize="26214400">
  <field name="_id" layout="${event-properties:item=CallIdentifier}"/>
  <field name="ts" layout="${event-properties:item=TimeStamp}" bsonType="DateTimeUtc"/>
  <field name="cap" layout="${event-properties:item=ApplicationCaller}" />
</target>
```

But i obtain this log in mongo (I don't wont circled data):

[image]

Please can anyone help me?? Thank you and sorry for my English

Comment: Please, nobody can help me?

Comment: Sorry, for what reason my post was downvoted?

Comment: See also https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/issues/20

Comment: That post is mine, but i’m not sure! I’m waiting for developer team answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would have to be a code change to accommodate this.  See [Issue](https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/issues/20) for more information.

New property `includeEventProperties` can now be configured:

```
<target xsi:type="Mongo"
        name="mongo"
        includeDefaults="false"
        includeEventProperties="false"
        connectionString="mongodb://localhost"
        collectionName="myCollection"
        databaseName="logs"
        cappedCollectionSize="26214400">
  <field name="_id" layout="${event-properties:item=CallIdentifier}"/>
  <field name="ts" layout="${event-properties:item=TimeStamp}" bsonType="DateTimeUtc"/>
  <field name="cap" layout="${event-properties:item=ApplicationCaller}" />
</target>
```

Just use ver. 4.6.0.68 from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Mongo

Comment: The post "Complete Custom Document duplicate info and properties" was mine. I see the new property IncludeEventProperties that you added to library. Thank you for solving the problem. However I still do not understand why they have downvote my original post. Bah

Answer (score 0):

This morning i have tried use the new version of library, this is the new configuration:

```
   <target xsi:type="Mongo"
        name="mongo"
        includeDefaults="false"
        connectionString="mongodb://localhost"
        collectionName="myCollection"
        databaseName="logs"
        cappedCollectionSize="26214400"
        includeEventProperties="false">
  <field name="_id" layout="${event-properties:item=CallIdentifier}"/>
  <field name="ts" layout="${event-properties:item=TimeStamp}" bsonType="DateTime"/>
  <field name="cap" layout="${event-properties:item=ApplicationCaller}" />
</target>
```

with new tag **includeEventProperties=false** and with its new property in the class MongoTarget and it works fine. This is the result:
[image]
Thank you so much, great job